# Android activity name

Tags: android

I have 3 activities and the flow is like this(1 → 2 → 3 ). at the 1st activity, upon pressing the button it should goto second activity.i want display the name of which activity we are going, is it possible to get name to activity wihtout toast

Regards
Thilag.

Comment: Well, without Toast, once you get the name using @Guillaume solution, you can dispaly the name in a TextView, or in the title or anywhere you want to.

Comment: please explain some what more about your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can pass activity class name through intent to next activity.

```
Intent obj =new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
Bundle bundleObj =new Bundle();`
bundleObj.putString(key,"ActivityName");
obj .putExtra(bundleObj);
StartActivity(obj);
```

Then in NextActivity,try to get bundle value which is your prevoius ActivityName

Comment: it will show the previous activity. but i want is launching activity

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand what you mean by "without toast".

Anyway, to get the "name" of an activity at runtime, just use:

```
String activityName = activity.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

If you're running that code from within the activity, just use:

```
String activityName = getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Comment: No problem - this is the internal class name of your activity though, so probably not something you want to display to your users

Comment: yeah i want to display activity name. when we are pressing button from first activity it should start the second activity that i want to display the second activity name.